# how to send individual mail using python with mailchimp

Tags: python, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I want to send mail using MailChimp. Like when user register then I want to send username and password email to the user with MailChimp. I have developed the website in Django 1.8. I also want to use MailChimp template in my Django application.

I have saw code but subscribed is required. And also it will send mail to list of user define MailChimp dashboard.

Comment: If its urgent, talk to MailChimp directly. We are not their customer support.

Answer (score 3):

This question doesn't fit the site (off-topic; doesn't ask a programming question; more of tech support for another site) - but while you are here, here's the answer you want. Again, you should contact them for this kind of question. Please read https://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/common-rookie-mistakes/html/

**Mistake: Confusing transactional emails with email marketing**

> Do you have a list of customers who have purchased products from your
>   e-commerce store? They’ll probably expect receipts and shipping
>   notifications via email. Those types of one-to-one messages are called
>   transactional emails, and they're different from email marketing.
>   That’s why we developed Mandrill. [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) is a delivery API for
>   MailChimp users who want to send transactional emails. Mandrill is
>   optimized for emails like password reminders, order confirmations,
>   receipts, and personalized notifications, and will help you manage and
>   monitor your transactional messaging through advanced tagging,
>   webhooks, and more.

As they say, MailChimp is not for *transactional* emails. Mandrill is.